# How to find out how many methods are added with a library in Android Studio/Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-multidex

What is the easiest way to find out how many methods do we add to our method count when we add a new library as a dependency in Android Studio project's gradle file, for example:

```
compile 'com.github.jkwiecien:EasyImage:1.2.1'
```

Answer (score 2):

with this library you can do it.

https://github.com/KeepSafe/dexcount-gradle-plugin

Answer (score 2):

Plugin methodscount.com works in Android Studio and provides exactly the required information. Though I found the standard Android Studio APK Analyzer more convenient for the purpose of method counting. This tool won't answer on how many methods in particular library it will rather come up with the real information and breakdown on methods count after all the gradle and proguard instructions. On practice it's sometimes even more convenient than theoretical answer about how many methods can be found in a library. I.e. using this info it's easier to experiment with proguard configurations and see adjusted method count.

APK Analyzer can be invoked this way:

**menu > Build > Analyze APK...**

More info:

[APK Analyzer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer.html)